# Using interceptor to attach the correct token after server responds with an 401 error

Tags: angular, rxjs, interceptor

I am trying to create an error-handling method for all authentication issues. I am running into an issue where my authTokenService.getAmadeusAuthToken$ method is being called but since it's a post-call that returns a new token, it takes longer to resolve, in the meantime the catchError obvservable  returns the next.handle before the token is retrieved. I have tried a few different ways and I don't know the best way to have interceptor method wait until the authTokenService.getAmadeusAuthToken$ is completed. Here is my code:

```
My Interceptor:

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
          tap(test => {
            this.authTokenService.getAmadeusAuthToken$().pipe(
            ).subscribe(token => {
            const authReq = req.clone({
              headers: req.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token.access_token)
            });
            return next.handle(authReq);
            })
          })
        )
      })
```

The method to post call to grab a new token

```
  getAmadeusAuthToken$():  Observable<any>{
const httpOptions = {  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")}
return this.http.post<Token>('https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token', this.body, httpOptions)
```

}

To make sure the intercept method works, I made an API call to just grab the new token and hardcoded it in. The intercept method work like a charm since there isn't a race condition and the interceptor returns the next.handle() with the token right away.

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         const authReq = req.clone({
              headers: req.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + "lkVkfilWizfcuyVpXBQsA08XkUy5")
            });
        return next.handle(authReq);
      })
```

So basically I want to make sure the interceptor waits for the authTokenService.getAmadeusAuthToken$ to finish getting the token, and only then return the new next.handle with the token, what am I missing here?

Comment: Add a tap inside empty pipe, move your subscribe callback and return statement inside there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, could you show an example of this?

Comment: Still have not been able to figure out how to make sure the auth call finishes before returning the handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This eliminates the race condition I had and makes sure the request waits for the new token response before trying the request again. This is a quick and dirty way of doing it, Further refinement will need to be done in order to cache the token in local storage and put in a filter for  specific error codes

```
 export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  token :  Token;
  idTokenPresent = false;
  authRequest: any;
  idToken: string | string[] | null;
  testreq: any;
  constructor(private authTokenService: AuthTokenService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return this.authTokenService.getAmadeusAuthToken$().pipe(
          switchMap(token => {
            this.authRequest = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token.access_token)
             });
            return next.handle(this.authRequest)
          })
        )
      }
    )
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `next.handle(...)`, you actually want to return an observable that first calls to get a new token, then executes the next request.

To avoid subscribing we can use `switchMap` to handle the subscribing for us:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return this.authTokenService.getAmadeusAuthToken$().pipe(
        switchMap(token => {
            const headers = req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.access_token}`);
            const authReq = req.clone({ headers });

            return next.handle(authReq);
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, Tried it out but that gives me a Stack Overflow error, Observable.js:53 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded,

Comment: I wonder if the next response is also returning error, thus causing an infinite loop.  Probably should add a errorHandling to next call as well... something like: `return next.handle(authReq).pipe(catchError(...)`

Comment: Tried implementing a catchError but I still keep getting the infinite loop, any suggestion on what I would return from the catchError

Comment: But regardless in order to properly filter out any error codes 401's  token expiration etc I would have to implement a catcherror directly on the handle.next method so that I can tap into what the request looks like right?